# Filter particular date in a DF column

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

### I want to filter particular date in a DF column.

> My code:

```
df
df["Crawl Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Crawl Date"]).dt.date
date=pd.to_datetime("03-21-2020")
df=df[df["Crawl Date"]==date]
```

> It is showing no match.
>   Note: df column is having time also with date which need to be trimmed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested your code with an example dataframe and it ran alright. Could you print out the content of the "Crawl Date" column to verify that it actually contains dates?

Comment: This code should work correctly. Can you edit it so as to make it reproducible ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script assumes that the 'Crawl Dates' column contains strings:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

column_names = ["Crawl Date"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
#Populate dataframe with dates
df.loc[0] = ['03-21-2020 23:45:57']
df.loc[1] = ['03-22-2020 23:12:33']

df["Crawl Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Crawl Date"]).dt.date    
date=pd.to_datetime("03-21-2020")
df=df[df["Crawl Date"]==date]
```

Then `df` returns:

> Crawl Date 0  2020-03-21

Comment: Crawl date is in below format: 
 3/21/2020 8:01 ,
3/21/2020 8:00
Name: Crawl Date, dtype: object

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example?